# Extract only text from ePub

Tags: php, html, zip, epub

I'm trying to do some text analysis on ebooks, so I need to extract the plain text from epub files. Below is example code from php.net which unzips the epub and then echos all its contents.

My problem is that it also tries to echo images so I get lots of this: `��̹,{ϥ㓦,�[k�رO?���` being echoed. Ideally It would just give me super-basic plain text. Any ideas on how to skip echoing a `$zip_entry` which is an image (or anything non-text)?

Thanks!

```
$zip = zip_open("book.epub");

if ($zip) {
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
        echo "Name:               " . zip_entry_name($zip_entry) . "\n";
        echo "Actual Filesize:    " . zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry) . "\n";
        echo "Compressed Size:    " . zip_entry_compressedsize($zip_entry) . "\n";
        echo "Compression Method: " . zip_entry_compressionmethod($zip_entry) . "\n";

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
            echo "File Contents:\n";
            $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
            echo "$buf\n";

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
        }
        echo "\n";

    }

    zip_close($zip);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a

```
content.opf
```

file in the root of unzipped epub? If so examine it's content. You should see something like:

```
<item id="chapter19" href="zzzzzzz.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
<item id="image1" href="images/yyyyy.jpg" media-type="image/jpeg" />
```

this should give you good idea how to avoid images.